# Coding in laravel Voyager

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, voyager

I'm using **Voyager** which is Laravel Admin that support BREAD operation. As part of my learning, I dig deep into their coding style. I'm confused about how they're calling and displaying side menu from 'resources/views/dashboard/sidebar.blade.php'.

```
<div id="adminmenu">
    <admin-menu :items="{{ menu('admin', '_json') }}"></admin-menu>
</div>
```

Any sort of help in understanding coding is highly appreciable!

Answer (score 1):

its a vue component

```
<admin-menu :items="{{ menu('admin', '_json') }}"></admin-menu>
```

should be found in in `Resources/js/component/AdminMenu.vue` its binding :items props data

if its not located there check `Resources/js/app.js` and search for `admin-menu` if you found check the directory of AdminMenu.vue Directory looks like this

```
Vue.component('admin-menu', require('./components/AdminMenu.vue').default);
```

Comment: Do you know how is menu( admin,json) being called?